# Clientlibs Qs How to exclude some js files

Tags: aem

I have clientlibs with category abc. It contains multiple js files e.g.

```
abc
  |-->JS
  |    |--->a.js
  |    |--->b.js
  |    |--->c.js
  |-->js.txt[which have the paths of all three js files]
```

If I use something like : `<cq:includeClientLib js="abc" />`. This include all my js files in my script. But how can i restrict to include only two. These 3 are just example, there can be 10 or more. Does anyone has any idea how this can achive excluding creating new clientlib folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this requirement using themes functionality of clientlibs. It will require few modifications to the clientlibs structure. Let me explain it with three js files (a.js , b.js and c.js).

Let's assume b.js is not required all the time where as a.js and c.js are. You will have  to create a parent clientlib with a.js and c.js. In the same clientlib create a theme folder and add a second clientlib with b.js [**should have same category as parent**], the structure should be as follows :

```
clientlibs: {
categories: [
    "themeParent"
],
jcr: primaryType: "cq:ClientLibraryFolder",
js: {
    jcr: primaryType: "nt:folder",
    a.js: {
        jcr: primaryType: "nt:file",
        jcr: content: {}
    },
    c.js: {
        jcr: primaryType: "nt:file",
        jcr: content: {}
    }
},
js.txt: {
    jcr: primaryType: "nt:file",
    jcr: content: {
        //a.js and c.js
    }
},
themes: {
    jcr: primaryType: "nt:folder",
    themeb: {
        categories: [
            "themeParent"
        ],
        jcr: primaryType: "cq:ClientLibraryFolder",
        js.txt: {
            jcr: primaryType: "nt:file",
            jcr: content: {
                //b.js
            }
        },
        b.js: {
            jcr: primaryType: "nt:file",
            jcr: content: {}
        }
    }
}
}
```

Themes can be selectively enabled for a clientlib using the [themed](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/taglib.html#%3Ccq:includeClientLib%3E) flag of includeClientLib tag.

`<cq:includeClientLib js="themeParent"/>` : will include a.js , c.js and b.js

`<cq:includeClientLib js="themeParent" themed="false"/>` : will include a.js and c.js

`<cq:includeClientLib js="themeParent" themed="true"/>` : will only include b.js

References : [How are themes applied in Adobe AEM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657364/how-are-themes-applied-in-adobe-aem)

Comment: Great job Sharath. But this helps in either/Or case. Say some times I want a combo of a.js and b.js and some times b.js and c.js then this approach won't work right?

Comment: @Oliver , that level of modularity is not supported. Why not have different categories in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the js file entry in the 'js.txt', js will be present in the path but will not be included as part of cq:include

Comment: please include sample code.It will be more better to understand

Comment: @AlbinJoseph : I assume there is no such code logic, Its a concept that i mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Girish Natashankar : Thats fine, but what is the case clientlib have many js files that needs to add in such manner. Its not seems good solution as far as i am familiar with clientlibs

Comment: @AEMExplorer: Do you have an specific requirement on why you need to remove only certain files ?

You can follow the solution suggested by Oliver OR

You can create multiple clientlibs and load which is necessary on the page and leave the other

Answer (score 0):

**To the best of my knowledge this is not possible.** Whatever js file names you enter in the js.txt  will be included when you write this `<cq:includeClientLib js="abc" />` statement in your JSP.

So say if you want to include  only two JS files in another JSP  without creating a new clientlib the only way to do it is include the manually using full path.

like this

```
<script src="/etc/designs/projectname/clientlibs/js/a.js"></script>
<script src="/etc/designs/projectname/clientlibs/js/b.js"></script>
```